# Modular model relationship traits for laravel eloquent models

Tags: laravel, architecture, eloquent, package, entity-relationship

I'm separating my code into small packages, utilizing the benefits of reusing these packages for other applications I'll come to development. ([Package Development](https://laravel.com/docs/packages))

Example Packages List:

- **UserPackage** *(could be combined to Access or AuthPackage, just an example)*
- **RolePackage** *(could be combined to Access or AuthPackage, just an example)*
- **PermissionPackage** *(could be combined to Access or AuthPackage, just an example)*
- **ContactPackage**
- **AddressPackage** (morphable relation)
- ...

If a app needs some packages, you will just require them by composer. So not all of them will always be used. And that's the case where i'm stuck how to design this.

Cuz, I'm looking for a clever way to separate models relationships in to small chunks of files, keeping the models as clean as possible.

I came up with two approaches: **Relationship-Trait** (with all related relationships for a given model) vs **HasRelation-Trait** (implementing on models that require a relationship)

But I can't work out which of these will be better suited in case of keeping the packages scaleable and modular. Especially, if I don't know if specific package will be installed.

**1. Relationship-Trait**

Model example

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Permissions extends Model
{

    /*
     * Every Model has a Relationships trait
     * containing all possible relationships
     */
    use \App\Traits\PermissionRelationships;

    //
}
```

Relationship trait example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait PermissionRelationships
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

same for `roles` which implements its own `RoleRelationships`-Trait, `users` which implements its own `UserRelationships`-Trait and many other models, which does the same

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait UserRelationships
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        // Package which maybe wouldn't be installed
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contact::class);
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }


    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

Has all relationships, even if the model of the relationship doesn't existing.

**2. HasRelation-Trait**
Again a model example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    /*
     * Implements the required relationships
     */
    use \App\Traits\Relationships\HasRoles; // or roleable
    use \App\Traits\Relationships\HasPermissions; // or permissionable

    //
}
```

*Where each trait only contains it's own relationship (which not always have to be many-to-many. A new trait, for one-to-on, one-to-many, morph, etc, will be required)*

Role-Trait

```
namespace App\Traits\Relationships;

trait HasRoles
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

Permission-Trait:

```
namespace App\Traits\Relationships;

trait HasPermissions
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }
}
```

Here I just can implement the trait on a model, I decide to use the relationship, even if it is not intended for this model. (I assume there will be irrational combinations)

Maybe there is a 3rd approach I did not think of, but when I on those two, I can't work out a good solution which will be beneficial for my package architecture. What to do in this situation?